# Как добавить origin в заголовок запроса к серверу?

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch, cors

У меня получается так, что к запросу нужно добавить origin с ссылкой домена, чтобы в ответ мне вернулся правильный заголовок. Можно ли как - то его добавить?

Я уже делал вот так -

На линуксе почему - то сам добавляет во всех браузерах, а на винде не хочет ни сам, ни если я пропишу. Возможно, что я не так пишу или не там, но пока сильно ничего по этому поводу не нашел

Comment: Он добавляется браузером автоматически при запросах к домену отличному от текущего

Comment: @AlexeyTen, понял, спасибо, буду знать.
Теперь значит нужно пойти смотреть, что на беке происходит